# Show Contact's Photo from retrieve SMS

Tags: java, android, contactscontract, smsmanager

I am able to retrieve SMS conversation from the query properly and it is working. Now I would like to add photo of particular contact? I was able to get the contact's display name by putting the following:

```
 Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(Nameuri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

            if(cs.getCount()>0)
            {
                cs.moveToFirst();
                contactName = cs.getString(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
```

I am not able to find PhoneLookup._ID? Is there any easy way retrieve photo similar to Display_name?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*You should read id of the contact in same query in which you are reading display name.  And then you should read [ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html) for an example code to read/ display Contact photo.*

[Android: Get Contact Details (ID, Name, Phone, Photo)](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/android-get-contact-details-id-name-phone-photo/) can be a very good example to solve your problem.

---

Modify your query as (I added `PhoneLookup._ID`)

```
Cursor cs= getContentResolver().query(Nameuri, new String[]{PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},PhoneLookup.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);
```

//And read the id as same as you read display name

```
long id = cs.getLong(cs.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup._ID));
```